# Redirect to user dashboard after successful login

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, ajax, authentication

I'm trying to redirect to my user-dash.html page after the user is successfully logged in.

I've already tried using res.redirect() and got an error about not setting headers after they've been sent to the client.

public.index.js:

```
// when the login from is submitted:

    $("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let username = $("#GET-username").val();
        let password = $("#GET-password").val();
        let userInfo = {username, password};
        let settings = {
            url:"/auth/login",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(userInfo),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('successfully logged in');
                localStorage.setItem("authToken", data.authToken);
                localStorage.setItem("currentUser", username);
                user = username;
                console.log(data);
                },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };
        $.ajax(settings);
    })
```

auth/router.js:

```
// The user provides a username and password to login
router.post('/login', localAuth, (req, res) => {
  const authToken = createAuthToken(req.user.serialize());
  res.json({authToken});
});

const jwtAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false});
```

right now, when submit is clicked, the user is successfully logged in but nothing happens i.e. the user isn't redirected to their dashboard.

Comment: In your success function you need to redirect `window.location.href = "/dashboard";`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- `window.location.href = '/dashboard'`
- if you're using React, you can use :
  `this.props.history.push('/dashboard')`

Add it inside function assigned to the `success` attribute